# Is it possible to determine a key's position in a list in an XSL-FO stylesheet?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I've got a list of objects that I'm referencing by a `<xsl:key>`, and I'm trying to figure out the order of the referred-to objects within an `<xsl:value-of>` (or similar block).

I have the following XML:

```
<document>
  <question>
    <text>Please demonstrate your compliance with some boring standard.</text>
    <answer>
      <attachment ref="11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555"/>
      <attachment ref="22222222-3333-4444-5555-666666666666"/>
    </answer>
  </question>
  <question>
    ...
  </question>

  <attachment id="11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555">
    <name>employee_names_and_titles.doc</name>
    ...
  </attachment>
  <attachment id="22222222-3333-4444-5555-666666666666">
    <name>standard_operating_procedures.doc</name>
    ...
  </attachment>
</document>
```

And the following XSLT:

```
<!-- Page Layout -->
<xsl:template match="document">
  <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="usLetter" page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in" margin-top="0.5in" margin-bottom="1in" margin-left="0.5in" margin-right="0.5in">
        <fo:region-body/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="usLetter">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
  </fo:root>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Question and Answer section -->
<xsl:template match="question">
  <fo:block font-weight="bold">
    <xsl:value-of select="text"/>
  </fo:block>
  <fo:block>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="question/answer">
  <fo:block>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="answer/attachment">
  <fo:block>
    Refer to <xsl:value-of select="key('attachments', @ref)/name"/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Appendix section -->
<xsl:key name="attachments" match="document/attachment" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="survey/attachment">
  <fo:block break-before="page" font-size="20pt" font-weight="bold">
    Appendix <xsl:number format="A"/>
  </fo:block>
  <fo:block>
    ...
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

My desired document layout is to have all of the questions and answers within one flow, with answers frequently referencing things that appear in a later appendix. In the appendix, each "attachment" should be on it's own page, and each attachment should be numbered incrementally.

All of this is happening as expected; however, the answer currently says **Refer to employee_names_and_titles.doc**, when what I'd really like is for it to say **Refer to Appendix A**.

Is there a way that I can figure out the position of attachment ref="1111..." in the list of attachments, within the scope of the question-and-answer section? Is there a better way of formatting my XML, so that perhaps I won't have this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can figure out the position of attachment
>   ref="1111..." in the list of attachments

You can count its preceding attachment siblings, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="answer/attachment">
  <fo:block>
   Refer to Appendix <xsl:number value="count(key('attachments', @ref)/preceding-sibling::attachment) + 1" format="A"/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Is the `count()` necessary? Wouldn't just `<xsl:number select="key('attachments', @ref)" format="A"/>` work in this case?

Comment: @DanielHaley I don't think you can do that in XSLT 1.0, which I presume is being used here.

Answer (score 0):

`xsl:number`, even in XSLT 1.0 (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#number), "inserts a number based on the position of the current node in the source tree", so if the references are 1:1 with attachments and in the same order, you can let the XSLT processor do the hard work:

```
<xsl:template match="answer/attachment">
  <fo:block>Refer to Appendix <xsl:number level="any" format="A"/></fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```